# ¿ Verificar que si en una cadena existen numeros enteros?

Tags: java, array, string

He realizado este código :

```
 public static void main (String []args){
    Lexico lex = new Lexico();
    String cadena = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cadena: ");
    System.out.println(lex.ingresarCadena(cadena));

 }   

    String[] Ecuacion1;
public  String ingresarCadena(String cadena)
    {
     String c ="";
     Ecuacion1 = cadena.split("(\\+|\\-|\\*|\\=|\\%|\\/)");
     for(int i = 0; i < Ecuacion1.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(Ecuacion1[i]);
    }
    return c;
 }
```

pero quiero hacer un método que me diga si ahí números enteros en ese vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu idea es correcta, puedes realizarlo usando un bucle para verificar cada carácter en la cadena,

```
   private static boolean checkNumericValues(String cadena){        

      String[] caracteres =  cadena.split("");
      for(int i = 0; i < caracteres.length; i++)
        {
           try{             
                Integer.parseInt(caracteres[i]);             
                return true; //Existe al menos un caracter numerico.
           }catch (NumberFormatException e){ 
               System.out.println(" is not a valid integer number : " + e.getMessage()); 
           }                         
        }     

        return false; //No existen caracteres numericos

   }
```

---

pero considero que la mejor opción sería usando una `REGEX` para detectar valores numéricos:

```
String regex = ".*\\d+.*";
```

crea un método para verificar si la cadena contiene valores numéricos, en caso de existir al menos un valor numérico el método retornara `true`, en caso contrario `false`:

```
private static boolean checkNumericValues(String cadena){        

  String regex = ".*\\d+.*"; 
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);      

  return  pattern.matcher(cadena).matches();

}
```